# CRUD opertions on files in JSON format

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jackson

After tedious studying on how Jackson works I manged to serialize/deserialize my POJO objects in JSON format. But thing that I can't find in scope of Jackson library is how to perform CRUD operations upon serialized objects or even if it is possible.

Namely I have list of objects which I serialize as JsonArray and I want to perform one of CRUD operations on object in that list. My question is how can it be done without deserializing whole list of objects and again serializing it with new values or without implementing some kind of custom parser which?

Comment: For your needs you can use custom serializer/deserializer in which you can define filter logic.

Comment: @eg04lt3r thanks for the answer. Any good article on filters?

Comment: You can check this simple article https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/01/custom-serializer-jackson/. Something similar for deserialization too, your custom class should extends JsonDeserializer.

Comment: @eg04lt3r I've read the article. Even before I asked this question I made custom serialization/deserialization but I really can't see how can I perform an update of object property in the json array with custom serialization/deserialization. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You if you want have abiltiy to make modifications into serialized Json object before complete deserialization, you can define custom deserializer.

Example:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Value deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        // there you can apply your custom logic to the JsonNode
        // and return value according to your business logic
        return new Value(...);
    }
}
```

You can use it for any object if register in ObjectMapper. Alternatively, you can use it with annotation on the class `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)`.

Comment: Yes I used that. But how can I detect changes in objects of array without reading whole array again?

Comment: For what purposes you need this?

Comment: I need to make a forum data model and serialization but without relational database.

Comment: Even if you do not need rdbms, you still need update data. For each client you should serialize data again or use cache and check data changes. Anyway this is not responsibility of Serializer/Deserializer. You should think in more convenient way how to build your architecture solution. Seems that you are on wrong way. And this is normal behavior when you read data from serialized data each time, like your array. Because this functionality is just for data transformation.